# Can't get all response headers from angular 2 with cors

Tags: angular, cors

I have an Angular 2 (`2.1.2`) client, ASP.NET Core as a backend with CORS enabled. Normal APIs (GET, POST, DELETE, ...) is working fine, my problem is when I try to retrieve headers from the response; particularly `Content-Disposition`. Here is a screen shot when I try to get a file content using Ajax.

[image: OPTIONS request]

[image: GET request]

As you can see there is a header called `Content-Disposition` in the GET response headers, but it is missing when I try to retrieve it from the Angular `http` service.

> A quick note, I am only using CORS in development.

Comment: Your server is probably missing `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-disposition` https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-cors-20140116/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header

Comment: I am still new to ASP.NET Core, but I have CORS enabled like this `options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder  => builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin())`, I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: That doesn't include `AllowAnyHeaders`. I don't know ASP.NET, I only know Angular2.

Comment: I forced add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:"Content-Disposition"` to each response, but still no luck.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think the problem of the OP is that all the response headers showing in the dev tools are not all accessible from the Http Response headers. I've noticed this same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly, the server needs to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header to notify the browser what headers may be exposed to JS.

Comment: Ups, it should be `access-control-expose-headers`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to configure the server so that it adds the response header

```
access-control-expose-headers: content-disposition
```

otherwise the browser won't make the header available to JavaScript.

Comment: Search for CORS

Comment: Thanks I found a good description of all the CORS headers - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Answer (score 8):

To be even more precise, in ASP.NET Core, you can configure it like this in your `Startup` class, in the `Configure` method:

```
app.UseCors(x =>
{
     x.WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition");
     // .. omitted
});
```