# Set response header along with a string

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am trying to send the token in the headers of an HTTP request from backend to the frontend along with sending my own defined string. However, I am getting an issue. The token is being printed as null on the client-side. I don't know why:

Here's my code:

> Node/Express

```
if (bcrypt.compareSync(passcode, results[0].password))
{
     const token = jwt.sign({id: email}, secret, {expiresIn: 86400 });
     console.log(token);
     if(results[0].userrights == 'full')
       {
          res.setHeader('x-access-token', token);
          res.send("Full Authorization");
       }

    //rest of the code
 }
```

> Angular

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/login', form.value, {responseType: "text", observe: 
                'response'})
  .subscribe(responseData => {
    console.log(responseData);
    console.log(responseData.headers.get('x-access-token'));  //prints null on the console
```

I have searched quite a bit and found different examples which is making it very confusing. I don't want to use response status rather my own defined string. I have tried different things to print the variable but it still is throwing as null.

Comment: what do you have if you print: `console.log(responseData.headers)` ?

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud, the header is showing two entries. content-length and content-type. Length has value of ["18"], content-type has value of "text/html; charset=utf-8"

Comment: and in your browser (for example chrome), in the network tab do you see your header `x-access-token` as response header of the request ?

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud, yes, x-access-token: [object Object]

Comment: ah `[object Object] ` thats weird, if you replace `res.setHeader('x-access-token', {auth: true, token: token});` by `res.setHeader('x-access-token', token);` in server side ?

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud, now I am getting the x-access-token: "eyJh...xxx" :)

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud, but the console is still not printing the token.

Comment: there is no uppercase in xhr response headers (network tab), like `X-Access-Token` or something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a browser extension to allow CORS requests then  `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` should be added to the headers on server side. Please try adding the following line: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', '*')`

[Angular2 's Http.post is not returning headers in the response of a POST method invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508187/angular2-s-http-post-is-not-returning-headers-in-the-response-of-a-post-method)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: thank you so much. It worked. I was adding `app.use(cors())` in my main server program and I thought it would automatically expose the headers for me. Thanks for clearing. :)